# Remove Index [number] from string

Tags: javascript, typescript

Using Typescript I have an array of objects as follows:

```
var errors = [
  { name: "Emails[2]", message: "Email is invalid" }
  { name: "Role", message: "Role is required" }
];
```

The `name` can be:
1. A string like `"Role`".
2. A string followed by brackets and number like `"Emails[2]"`.

In case of (2) I would like to replace `"Emails[2]"` simply by `"Emails"`.

Every object with `name`=`text[number]` would have the `name` updated to `text`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please show us an attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: Are you familiar with regular expressions?

Comment: How to search and replace a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use map and replace

```
\[\d+\]$
```

- `\[` - Matches `[`
- `\d+` - Matches one or more digits
- `\]` - Matches `]`
- `$` - End of string

---

```js
var errors = [
  { name: "Emails[2]", message: "Email is invalid" },
  { name: "Role", message: "Role is required" },
  { name: "Role random [123]", message: "Role is required" }
];


let op = errors.map(({name,...rest})=>{
  name = name.replace(/\[\d+\]$/,'').trim()
  return {
    name,
    ...rest
  }
})

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `map()` and `replace()` with regex `/\[.*?\]/`

```js
var errors = [
  { name: "Emails[2]", message: "Email is invalid" },
  { name: "Role", message: "Role is required" }
];

errors= errors.map(i => {
  i.name = i.name.replace(/\[.*?\]/,'');
  return i;
});
console.log(errors);
```